# I need to generate a NAVISION Security Report for our auditors

Tags: navision, microsoft-dynamics-nav, dynamics-nav-2009

Is there a report in NAV 2009 that will show users and their roles?
Does anyone know what tables in the SQL database they might be in?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a report for that.

In **NAV 2009** in table **2000000053 (Windows Access Control)** you can check that info. Here you have `Role ID` and `Login ID` this table is for **Windwos logins**, for **DataBase Login** you can check the table **2000000003 (Member Of)** here you have `User ID` and `Role ID` fields.